# Convert Pandas float64 column containing NaNs to object column containing integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As the title says, I have a Pandas data frame that contains a `float64`, which represents integers. I'd like to convert it to use `int64`, but it also contain `NaN` values. As such, the best I can do is to convert it to have type `object`, converting all the non-`NaN` values to integers. What's the best way to do this without manually iterating over the column?

This is needed so that when I convert the data frame using `to_sql`, a nullable integer type is used instead of float.

For example:

```
>>> df
   a    b
0  1  2.0
1  3  NaN
```

What I'd like:

```
>>> df
   a    b
0  1    2
1  3  NaN
```

Comment: Did you try [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)?

Comment: df.astype(object)

Comment: `df["b"].astype("int64")` will result in `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`. I could convert to `"object"`, but I wasn't sure how to proceed from there without manually iterating over each value, checking if it was equal to `NaN`, and casting it conditionally.

Answer (score -1):

Try use `.apply`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"s": [2.0, np.nan]})
print(df["s"].apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else np.int64(x)))
```

**Output:**

```
0     2
1   NaN
Name: s, dtype: float64
```